# Why the input doesnt work when generated by React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

This input work correct, when i just add it to the `index.html`. But it doesnt work when generated by react. The nums in input form just dont changing. Why is this happening?

```
<input type="date" name="date" value="2003-12-16" max="2021-07-03"/>
```

Comment: It's because you have used `value` and make it uncontrolled. So It is not controlled by React now. You should use `defaultValue` attribute instead of `value`

Comment: Have a read here: https://itnext.io/controlled-vs-uncontrolled-components-in-react-5cd13b2075f9

Comment: see [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your goal you have go with React way ([Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)):

```
<input type="date" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} max="2021-07-03" />
```

Working demo: [Codesandbox](https://codepen.io/rashedrahat/pen/KKmxKvy)

To know about `Uncontrolled Components` please visit: [Uncontrolled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)